# "Nothing to do" when installing mysql devel

Tags: mysql, centos, yum

I'm using CentOS 6.4 and trying to install mysql-devel by "yum"
It cannot be installed and there is no error message. I can use "yum search" to find a package but cannot install it.

```
/home/centos64/ce-installer:sudo yum install MySQL51-devel.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink
epel-debuginfo/metalink
epel-source/metalink
 * epel: mirrors.ptd.net
 * epel-debuginfo: mirrors.servercentral.net
 * epel-source: mirrors.servercentral.net
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
base
centosplus
epel-debuginfo
epel-source
extras
updates
webtatic
Setting up Install Process
Nothing to do
```

Thanks.

Comment: That rather implies that it's already installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out whether already installed:

```
rpm -qa | grep -i mysql
```

Comment: it's seem the package is already installed, but it didn't show that "package is already installed" but a confused message "Nothing to do"

Comment: @1mdc yeah. that's very confusing. I tested before post answer. but in my case (CentOS 6) ".. already installed.. " shown correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have the name of the package wrong. Yum returns "nothing to do" because there is no "MySQL51-devel.x86_64" package available. Try this:

```
sudo yum install mysql-devel.x86_64
```

Comment: hello. if yum can't find package name, yum issues "No package XXXX available. Nothing to do" there is no 'No package...' (I use CentOS). Sorry if I am wrong.